# Need an answer for this with some explanation

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
void main (){
    int i, j;
    for (i=0, j=5; j >0, i < 10; i ++, j--)
        printf("\nClub Excel");
}
```

What will be the output?

Comment: seriously, that's your question??

Comment: Have you tried running it? what did you get?

Comment: See for yourself: http://ideone.com/kNlPt

Comment: `operator ,` has returns the value of its right operand, that is `a,b` has the same value as `b`. Therefore, your for loop runs 10 times because `j>0,i<10` is the same as `i<10`

Comment: I think the OP does not understand why that behavior. And S/He seems to have made a mess of the Q by quoting `Need an Answer`, `Need an explanation` with the output of program should have been the right way to ask this Q.

Answer (score 2):

If you have compiled that code, You see a warning:

```
prog.c:4: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
```

It tells you that in this usage of comma operator the statement on the R.H.S of the comma  is taken in to consideration while the one on L.H.S is ignored.

This basically means the condition checked used for the `for` loop is:

```
i < 10
```

while,

```
j >0
```

is ignored since it is on LHS of the comma expression.